# AssignedLicense with disabledPlans in MS 365 dev program account

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to assign a license (dev license E5) with a disabled service plan (named "SWAY") to a user using Microsoft Graph API.

```
graphClient.users(uid.getUidValue()).assignLicense(
                            UserAssignLicenseParameterSet.newBuilder()
                                    .withAddLicenses(toBeAdded)
                                    .withRemoveLicenses(Collections.emptyList()).build()
                    ).buildRequest().post();
```

If have taken the *skuId* und *service plan guid* from a call to list subscribed sku. However, when I execute above code then an error is returned:

> com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code:
> Request_BadRequest Error message: User inherits a license from a group
> membership and it cannot be directly modified on the user. License
> Sku: DEVELOPERPACK_E5, Account: cognitumdev
>
> POST
> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/88a4c568-346d-4c9f-8752-8e03d16f0a6e/microsoft.graph.assignLicense
> SdkVersion : graph-java/v3.5.0 [...]
>
> 400 : Bad Request

I'm confused about the error message because I do not assign the license to a group but directly to the user. So what does that error mean?

Moreover, I can disable that app "SWAY" via ms 365 admin center for a licensed user without problems. Querying the assigned licenses of the corresponding user afterwards gives the same *assignedLicense* I was trying to assign via API without success.

Comment: Would you share the request-id so we can help look into this?

Comment: @Diana Re-executed the request with follow "innerError": `{"date":"2021-06-03T12:45:12","request-id":"18b77f6d-1208-4e12-b062-abbaa1c6a019","client-request-id":"e4c79692-b6bb-4db2-9dc2-42fbf29f88c8"}`. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: @Diana Did you find anything?